# How to "pivot" data with unequal resulting columns using Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I am struggling to convert some data.  I want to go from this:

```
Faculty, Course
Jane Doe, BW 401-01
Jane Doe, BW 402-01
John Doe, BW 101-01
John Doe, BW 101-02
John Doe, BW 103-01
```

To this:

```
Faculty, Course01, Course02, Course03
Jane Doe, BW 401-01, BW 402-01,
John Doe, BW 101-01, BW 101-02, BW 103-01
```

The data could have any number of faculty and any number of courses. 
I have tried playing with Pivot and UnPivot but neither do what I want. Any ideas of how I would approach this in Power Query?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crucial trick is to get a "Running Count" column for each Faculty. I use a technique built on a Index column, together with a Grouped Query that calculates the Min Index for each Faculty.

You can then format that "Running Count" and run the Pivot on it to produce column headings like Course01, Course02.

I built a working solution which you can download from my OneDrive and try out:

http://1drv.ms/1AzPAZp

It's the file: **Power Query demo - Pivoting based on a running count**

Comment: Awesome!  Worked like a charm.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code snippet, it may resolve the issue-

```
 = Table.SplitColumn(Table.Group(Source, {"Faculty"}, {"a", each [Course]}),"a",each _,{"Course01","Course02","Course03"})
```